# Emacs C-x C-s save command creates duplicates

Tags: linux, emacs, command-line

When I save a file in emacs (using C-x C-s) and then exit, the file is duplicated, but one file ends in a "~".  For example, if I saved a file test.txt in emacs, my directory would show the files test.txt and test.txt~ after saving.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're a backup copy, and can be very useful if something gets screwed up with your documents. However, you can [change the directory](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory) they're saved in to something other than the current directory.

From the linked document:

> If you don’t want to clutter up your file tree with Emacs’ backup
>   files, you can save them to the system’s “temp” directory:
>
> ```
> (setq backup-directory-alist
>       `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
> (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
>       `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
> ```
>
> This will all place all auto-saves and backups in the directory
>   pointed to by temporary-file-directory (e.g., C:/Temp/ on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

The file whose name ends in a tilde `~` is a backup copy. It should contain what was in the file before you started Emacs.